# Switching Database in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq, linq-to-sql

How can we change the underlying database for Linq based WebApp ?

**for example:**

When we release our web application, say to release from production, if using ADO.NET,
it is as simple as modifying **connection string** in **web.config** to point towards the live Database in use. The databases are almost identical, other data stored..

What and how do we change unerLying Database when using LINQ ?

**Note ;** Using c#

thanks

Comment: is there no connection string in web.config?
there should be one with the attribute providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: There is one, but need to keep both there, for live and production.
Needed to swap them when releasing product, not manually removing /editing same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend in your app instantiating the data context with the connection string overload.  I create a helper component that does:

```
public static class DCHelper
{
  public static MyDataContext Create()
  {
     return new MyDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);
  }
}
```

That way, I only have one place to change the way the context is instantiated, or I can change the config file to switch databases.  Or, the create method can take some input to determine the connection.

Answer (score 4):

You should still be able to do the same; `DataContext` (including the SqlMetal generated ones) include constructor overloads that accept a connection string. Just fetch the string you want from `ConfigurationManager` (or whatever) and pass it in.

Actually, if you don't mind hacking the DBML directly, it does actually support reading from `ConfigurationManager` *directly*; the problem is that the IDE designer hates this, and breaks it every time you look at it. Which is a shame ([discussed here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/2a1c0cfa-2dc1-4bcb-8c65-2bb65f0f7c7a/)).

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to know how you can move the [connection string to the Web.Config](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/203567.aspx) Rick Strahl has an [example](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/203567.aspx) on his blog.

If you want to change to a different type of database... You can probably save most (if not all of the queries.)  But you will need to change the provider/repository.  [LINQ 2 SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) only support MSSQL at this time (and that is all it is really meant to do.)

Check out [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) if you need more flexibility.

Comment: Pretty sure OP is asking about changing the connection string, not the type of database

Comment: Databases are are of same type (SQL SERVER 2005), The difference is for "production DB" and "Live DB"

Comment: Yeah I saw that after I posted my answer.  I added a note to that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do appreciate